# using Request.QueryString and Eval in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, eval

this is a link using eval and Request.QueryString :

```
<a href='<%"/City.aspx?City=" = Request.QueryString["City"]; %> + <%#Eval("CatID") %>' class="btn btn-default">link1</a>
```

there is a syntax error I Can't figure out

Comment: Error for "/City.aspx?City=" and says The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer.

Comment: Where is this anchor tag, in a datagrid, datalist, etc...?

Comment: It is inside a listview

Answer (score 3):

You can try out this code:

```
<a href="/City.aspx?City='<%# Request.QueryString["City"] %>' + 
<%#Eval("CatID") %>" class="btn btn-default">link1</a>
```

Comment: no error but when I click on the link url look like this:     "City.aspx?City=%27tehran%27%20+%20%277", where %27%20 came from? and when I click on the link again and agian it adds %20%20%27... to end of the url. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first "=" to a "+"

```
<a href='<%"/City.aspx?City=" + Request.QueryString["City"]; %> + 
<%#Eval("CatID") %>' class="btn btn-default">link1</a>
```

Comment: No, this time says Only assignments, call increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following :

```
<a href='<%#"/City.aspx?City="+ Request.QueryString["City"]+"+" %><%#Eval("CatID") %>'
                        class="btn btn-default"><%#Eval("CatName") %></a>
```